# Paradigmatic way to set base class with multiple inhertiance

Tags: c++

I'm wondering if the following is the paradigmatic way to set a base class in the case of multiple inheritance. Are there any pitfalls to this approach?

```
#include <iostream>
struct A
{
    int one, two;
};
struct B
{
    int three, four;
};
struct C : A, B
{
    C(int One, int Two, int Three, int Four) : A({ One, Two }),B({ Three, Four }){}
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    C myC( 1, 2, 3, 4);
    //a lot of code here
    B myB={ 9, 10 };
    static_cast<B&>(myC)= myB;//Code smell?
    std::cout << myC.three <<","<<myC.four<< std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Class hierarchies (single or multiple inheritance) and assignment rarely work together. Do you have a real use case?

Comment: Certainly, I had a large structure that contains the program settings. Occasionally, GUI interfaces are used to configure a part of this settings information. In which case `static_cast<RenderSettings&>(channel_settings) = getRenderSettings()``. In a normal world the settings would live in the GUI but I'm trying for a strong separatation between the two components for testing.

Comment: Prefer composition over inheritance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably safer than `static_cast`:

```
template<class T, class U>
T implicit_cast(U&& u){return std::forward<U>(u);}
```

as it cannot do anything other than implicitly cast.

```
implicit_cast<B&>(myC)= myB
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, the fact you even want to do this is a code smell, since assignment operators and class hierarchies often do not mix well.

However, one way is to provide class `C` appropriate assignment operators.  One which accepts an argument of type `const A &` and the other which accepts a `const B &`.   Then

```
myC = some_a;
myC = some_b;
```

will work, without any need to muck around with implicit or explicit casting.

If you have trouble implementing such an assignment operator, then that is usually a sign of more things wrong with your design.    The list of problems such difficulty might suggest is too long for this format.

Bear in mind that, practically, if an assignment operator is needed, then so is a corresponding constructor and (possibly) move constructor.